# Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\myAppPoolName' and cannot add new user for this

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis

I am getting the following error while asp.net app trying to connect database. `Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\myAppPoolName'.`

I use ms SqlServer 2008 r2, windows server 2008 r2.

This happened when I've just moved the application and database from one server to another.

I thought adding a new user to database named 'IIS APPPOOL\myAppPoolName' but when i try it, I'm getting following error on adding new db user wizard:

```
'IIS APPPOOL\myAppPoolName' is not a valid name because it contains invalid characters. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15006)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Erdem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, custom application pools receive the 'Network Service' user credentials.
Simply try adding a new login for your mssql server (and database, of course) for the 'Network Service' account.
[Read more here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Thank you @Nissim it was very helpful. I added new Sql Server login and select its' initial database as my application Db, instead of adding new db user. This fixed this situation.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Nissim

In Sql > Security > Logins > Right-click > new login > Login name "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

In Same New login window On left side > User Mapping > Check the database you want > Select each database and in Database roles (second box below) > db_owner

Click Ok

In IIS > Application Pools > Your app pool > advance settings > Identity (change to "NetworkService")

Click Ok

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix this without adding new SQL login simply Change App pool Identity to LocalSystem

Right click on the App pool > Advanced Settings > then change Identity to **LocalSystem**